# Image Magick - Creating animated gif less weight than Photoshop

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I could create a less weight animated gif with same variables(colors, dither, etc) using the following function:

```
convert -delay 4 -loop 0 *.png -coalesce -matte -alpha remove -depth 8 -layers optimizeFrame -colors 128 animated.gif
```

But there is a Photoshop function called "Includes transparency based on color opacity" that loose a lot of weight, and I can't find an Image Magick equivalent function.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `-alpha background`

Comment: Thanks Mark, but results same size

Comment: Can you post a few of the images you are using and the sort of results you achieve and the sort of results you expect - in terms of filesize and appearance?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I have to del -coalesce

```
convert -delay 4 -loop 0 *.png -matte -alpha remove -depth 8 -layers optimizeFrame -colors 128 animated.gif
```